# vulkano, how do you use ValidationFeatureEnableEXT?

Tags: rust, graphics, vulkan

I am trying to port a vulkan project from C++ into rust.

Right now I am trying to translate the following snippet:

```cpp
    auto enabled = vk::ValidationFeatureEnableEXT::eBestPractices;
    vk::ValidationFeaturesEXT features;
    features.enabledValidationFeatureCount = 0;
    features.pEnabledValidationFeatures = &enabled;
```

I have looked into the docs and I cannot, for the life of me, find a definition that maps into  VkValidationFeatureEnableEXT.

In fact looking into the definition of the create info struct

https://docs.rs/vulkano/latest/vulkano/instance/struct.InstanceCreateInfo.html

I don't even see the pNext field which all structs in vulkan need for extended functionality.

How do I use extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Create the Vulkan library:

```rust
let library = VulkanLibrary::new().expect("No local Vulkan library/DLL");
```

Create an `InstanceExtensions` struct with `ext_validation_features` set to true, and don't forget to also enable the extensions required for windowing:

```rust
let enabled_extensions = InstanceExtensions {
    ext_validation_features: true,
    ..vulkano_win::required_extensions(&library)
};
```

Add the best practices validation feature to a `Vec`:

```rust
let enabled_validation_features = vec![ValidationFeatureEnable::BestPractices];
```

Finally, create the instance:

```
Instance::new(
    library,
    InstanceCreateInfo {
        enabled_extensions,
        enabled_validation_features,
        ..Default::default()
    },
)
.expect("Failed to create instance")
```

Answer (score -2):

Might be late (and this might be a recent addition, after the question was asked), but the [`InstanceCreateInfo`](https://docs.rs/vulkano/latest/vulkano/instance/struct.InstanceCreateInfo.html) struct described in the question actually supports the extension `VkValidationFeatureEnableEXT`, with the following members:

```
pub enabled_validation_features: Vec<ValidationFeatureEnable>,
pub disabled_validation_features: Vec<ValidationFeatureDisable>,
```

which allow to pass which features to enable across those disabled by default, and which features to disable among those enabled by default.

Of course, it's also necessary to set `ext_validation_features` in the `enabled_extensions` field of the same struct.